# Redirect to an external url in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to do a redirect in **next.config.js** to an external url.

```
{
    source: '/hello',
    destination: 'https://google.com',
    permanent: false,
}
```

But when I visit **mywebsite.com/hello** redirects to **mywebsite.comhttps://google.com** instead of **https://google.com** (not tested in production, just local)

Do you know how can I configure a redirect to an external url?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Next v11/12 and Webpack 5, using an async `redirects()` function that returns an array of redirects inside of `next.config.js` is [best practice](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites):

```js
// next.config.js (Next 12 / Webpack 5)
module.exports = {
    
  // Redirects
  // First example shows wildcard functionality, all `/blog` to `/news`
  // Second example mirrors your use case
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/blog/:slug*',
        destination: '/news/:slug*',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/hello',
        destination: 'https://google.com',
        permanent: false,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The older Next v10 with Webpack 4 worked a little differently. I'd typically leverage some Node plugins - `next-compose-plugins` and `next-images` (this was before `next/images` was a thing).

The basic idea is you're setting up a plugin to make Webpack assembly easier, and one of the plugins processes your imagery during build. You add all of the next config options into an object that the `withPlugins` wrapper is ready to receive.

```js
// next.config.js (Next 10 / Webpack 4)
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')
const withImages = require('next-images')

const { 
  PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER, 
  PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD 
} = require('next/constants')

const nextConfig = {

  // Set redirects here, objs in arr as needed
  async redirects() {
    return []
  }
}

// This uses phases as outlined here: 
// https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-env-from-next-config-js
module.exports = withPlugins([

  // Processes images during build time
  [withImages, {
    [PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER]: 'http://localhost:3000',
    [PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD]: 'https://example.com'
  }]
   
], nextConfig)
```

Comment: I'm using Next.js 10.2.3 and webpack 4, may this be the reason?

Comment: @jacin - updated with Next 10/Webpack 4 example I found on an older project of mine. I used some plugins but this site is still online and doing fine, should work well for you.